# Dynamic CRM login issue due to msedge private mode

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, playwright, incognito-mode

Not able to login through script. Issue detail

> To access your service,app or website you may need to sign into Microsoft Edge profile using user credentials.

I have tried to sync the profile but no luck as playwright launch browser instance in private mode.

Tech stack: Playwright with C#

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Because you're forced into private/incognito mode, you'll have to update your tooling to provide authentication details

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.